# Need help identifying a new plant/weed? in my garden

Tags: identification

this appeared under Norway maple, but nowhere else in my yard. Can't find it on the Internet (yet). Deer/something ate it at first but stopped.
[image: plant]

[image: roots]

[image: stem]

I've added a picture of the stem. I think the other weed had opposite leaves, while mine doesn't. The stem is hollow, and does not exude any sap. It does not have a significant taproot. There are no spines/prickers on the leaves.I think it is a Nabalus albus/Prenathes alba, a/k/a White Snake Root or White lettuce.

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe the plant: size, shape, etc. and where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: @Brenn The family is the same (but unfortunately one of the biggest and most difficult family) but IMHO a different tribe. To me it seems Artichoke (Cynara)

Comment: Agreed, it's very difficult for a specific identification within this genus. Perhaps we'll eventually see a flower.

Comment: Glad to see you've made progress with the ID. I agree that it's different than the Blue lettuce. I've retracted my duplicate vote.